# Texture in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

I tried to put texture in a *BoxGeometry* in ThreeJS, but i fail, I was used absolute path, in the same directory all fail.

My script, Thanks in advance.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);

scene.add(light);

const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.5);

scene.add(light1);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(

    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true });

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 100, 100 );

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xf3ffe2,

    map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img.png'), // problem

    specular:0xffffff,
    shininess:1   
});

const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

cube.position.set(0,0,-200);
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 250; 

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.z += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Chances are you're running into a CORS issue if you're pointing to an image in your hard-drive. You'll need to set up a local server. See [this page in the documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally) for how to load image assets locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images need to be on a server to render effectively. Like marquizzo pointed out.
I always had that problem.

My advise for safe workflow:

Always work if possible through https://threejs.org/editor/ to texturise, if you have complex texture work blender might be a previous super to unwrap UV and do the work, then export to GLB, import in threejs editor to add lighting and fine-tune the look. When you are happy, the publish your work

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

i've tired your code and it worked , i offer you to use 'meshStandardMterial' and put the `new THREE.TextureLoader()` in a variable out of mesh object . it works .